# PHP - preg_match() no está funcionando correctamente

Tags: php

Mi paterno para `preg_match()` parece no ser el correcto o simplemente la función no está haciendo su trabajo.

Código:

```
$content = strtolower(file_get_contents($file));
$functions = ["`", "shell_exec", "exec"];
foreach($functions as $function){
  if(preg_match(“/“.$function.”/“, $content)) {
    $files[] = $file;
  }
}
```

La función no returna ningún tipo de error, simplemente `preg_match()` está retornando falso.

La variable `$file` es la ruta a un archivo existente (clase/objeto de PHP), utilizo este código para detectar si este utiliza funciones que podrían considerarse peligrosas, acompañado de un `strtolower()` en caso de que la función no esté escrita toda en minúscula, ya que los nombres de las funciones en PHP no son sensibles a las mayúsculas.

El archivo que estoy escaneando con `preg_match()` tiene un contenido similar a este:

```
class Main extends PluginBase implements Listener{

  public function onEnable(){
    $this->getLogger()->info(“Enabling “ . $this->getDescription()->getFullName().”...”);
    ShElL_eXeC(“df -Th”);
  }

}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Comprendo que has tenido problemas de sesión pero, por favor, no uses las respuestas para poner comentarios o mensajes a otros usuarios. Si tienes problemas con la cuenta, intenta recuperar la contraseña via email, y si tienes problemas contacta con los moderadores.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear un patrón que detecte las funciones junto con sus parámetros ya que de lo contrario se puede cumplir el match cuando se encuentra una palabra que contenga exec, como por ejemplo un comentario de tipo:

> //exec y shell_exec han sido desactivadas por motivos de seguridad

**Prueba con esto y dime si te funciona**

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);
    $functions = ["shell_exec", "exec"];
    foreach ($functions as $function) {
        if (preg_match("/\b$function\(.*?\)/i", $content)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }
```

Te dejo también un enlace donde podrás seguir adaptando el patrón: https://regex101.com/r/eS0rI9/7

Comment: Buenas tardes, probé tu código y la función esta arrojando el siguiente error PHP: `preg_match() Unknown modifier ‘g’`

Comment: Hola Ignacio, Eliminalo o cambia preg_match por preg_match_all

Comment: @Infobuscador Hola, buenas. Tu código no me resulta. Aquí te dejo el enlace a mi código completo. El método onEnable() es llamado y hace debug en la consola de mi aplicación [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kenygamer/1e5b7e09d772fe86e6871f6e49769a68)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar de esta manera

```
$rawContent = file($file);
$content = implode(" ",$rawContent);
$functions = ["`", "shell_exec", "exec"];
foreach($functions as $function){
  if(preg_match("/$function/",$content,$arrMatches)) {
    $files[] = $file;
  }
}
```